# Why do I need to throw NullPointerException in the main method?

Tags: java

Why do I need to throw NullPointerException in the main method? and what is going on in the "catch" block? It would be a great help if anybody could explain in detail. Thanks in Advance

```
public class GFG {

public static void main(String[]args) throws NullPointerException {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the array size");
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    int [] arr= new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i <arr.length ; i++) {
        arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    printRepeating(arr);
}

static void printRepeating(int[]arr){

     Map<Integer,Integer> map= new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        try {
            map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            map.put(arr[i], 1);
        }


    }
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e:map.entrySet()) {
        if(e.getValue()>1)

            System.out.print(e.getKey()+" ");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: "Need" to throw it? You don't. `NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException`, and you don't need to declare those. (It also indicates a programming bug.)

Comment: I'd suggest you spend a few days studying up on exceptions -- what they are, how they occur, how to diagnose them, how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to throw a `NullPointerException`. This exception extends from `RuntimeException`, so it is an unchecked exception. These exceptions are not checked during the compilation (the compiler does not have to specify them or catch them). These are related to mistakes inside the code itself; I suggest reading about unchecked exceptions. Only high-level programs throw these exceptions so I suggest changing the code to:

```
try {
    if (map.containsKey(arr[i]){
        map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
    }else{
        map.put(arr[i], 1);
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would remove the try and catch, but it is still safe having them. If you still want to throw it, here is how:

```
try {
    map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) + 1);
}catch (NullPointerException e) {
    map.put(arr[i], 1);
}
```